# Does PyCharm remote interpreter introduced encoding issue?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have this piece of code below to report an error:

```
 def get_name(self, name_dir):
       
        name = {}
        for cnt, line in enumerate(open(name_dir, 'r')):
            id, gname = line.strip().split('\t')
            name[id] = gname
        return name
```

The error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am running it in python3 both locally on Mac and on Ubuntu machines, and there are no errors. However, when I set up a remote interpreter in PyCharm to use the same python3 interpreter on the ubuntu machine, it reports the errors.

I fixed the problem by adding encoding='utf8' to the file 'open' function. Does that mean PyCharm introduced the error while configuring the remote interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PyCharm does what it means to do.

The problem is that *you tried locally both on Mac and Ubuntu*, which it is good, but this hides that your local computer have **locales**, which probably support UTF-8, but not the remote computer.

Now, by default, most Linux distribution install users with a UTF-8 locale, so I assume one of the two (the second it way more probable from my point of view):

- you installed Ubuntu with a very tiny image, without many (or any) locales. Or the locale you want to use is not installed, and Ubuntu find just the default locale as fall back (the `C` locale).
- or you are using root. Root usually (and for portability) uses just `C` locale, which supports only ASCII charset.

So, I assume, in your remote machine you are not using a UTF-8 locale. Try to run `export LANG=en_US.utf8` (a very common locale), to see if this solve the problem, or just the same string that `echo $LANG` returns in your local Ubuntu (or Mac). Note: `locale -a` will list all installed locales (ev. you must install/activate additional locales).

Note: it the reason is that you are using root, you have the difficult decision: either set default root locale to `en_US.utf8` or to `C.utf8` (on non interactive shell keep `C` or `en US` as language, or many scripts will fails).

My personal take: root programs should write just ASCII characters. There are files and logs for UTF-8 data. To write in console, just use a fallback `replace` or `backslashreplace` (for security reason, I would never use `ignore` in root).

In any case, also your code is not ideal, and you find that writing `encoding='utf8'` solve the problem. Python mantra includes: *explicit is better then implicit*, so if you know the encoding of `name_dir`, just use it, instead of letting Python (not PyCharm) to find out the local encoding (which in your case, it seems ASCII). Python uses [locale.getpreferredencoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) to find default locale.

So, it is not PyCharm, but the problem is in your remote locale (which it is used by default by Python). And I would solve the problem by putting explicitly the encoding on `open` (and on `write`). But if you are not running the program as root, I would also check why your remote user is not using by default a UTF-8 locale.

Comment: Yes, I am using 'root' on Ubuntu. Also, echo $LANG returns 'en_US.UTF-8' both on Mac and Ubuntu. So what you mean is that, 'root' user can use UTF-8 locale locally on linux, but not remotely. Is that right?

Comment: Check the .bashrc and .bash_profile. Often there are different settings between "interactive shell" or "normal shell". If you log remotely you have interactive shell, but if you exec a script directly, such script may just have a C locale. Try to write `sys.environment['LANG']` just to see what Python see.